# Linking external CSS using Styles.Url

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between these two:

```
<link href="@Styles.Url("~/Content/app/css/app.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="appcss" />
```

and

```
<link href="/Content/app/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="appcss" />
```

System.Web.Optimization documentation says that `Styles.Url` generates a version-stamped URL for a bundle.

I have not noticed in non-debug configuration `debug="false"` any change to the file content (due to optimisation) nor to its name / url.

Is there any potential benefit to use the first option over the second one?

Comment: Is "~/Content/app/css/app.css" a bundle? Because it looks like a file path.

Comment: No, it is just app.css file in /Content/app/css/. I got the first option from my theme. Would being a bundle change anything?

Comment: Your first full sentence ends with "generates a version-stamped URL for a **bundle**"... so I assume so?

Comment: Double checked, it is not a bundle. I would understand it if it would change the css file name (version-stamped) which can be later used to build a bundle. Might be it changes the file name if we put as a parameter a bundle not a file.

Comment: Since it's not a bundle, I doubt it even reads the file; it just puts the relative URL into the HTML, just like your second snippet. If it's in a bundle, then it will read the file, and create a "hash" of its contents, which it would use to create a unique file name. That's the benefit of using `@Styles.Url()` over just normal URL. There's also the use of the `~` with makes it easier to deploy to a different folder, whereas using just the plain href means you'd have to edit that link.